# How to add one image over other in Android

Tags: android, xml

I want to make a view in which one image view, say `iv_up` should be placed above the another image view, say `iv_down`.

The `iv_up` should be slighty transparent. One more thing, the `iv_down` happens to be an QR Code.

Is there any way to implement this?
Below is the code that I have written so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_down"
        android:layout_width="419dp"
        android:layout_height="419dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="QR CODE"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"/>

   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_up"
        android:layout_width="419dp"
        android:layout_height="419dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="QR CODE"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"/>

 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So take a look at this sample XML I have created:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_down"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:contentDescription="QR CODE"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_up"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:contentDescription="QR CODE"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/iv_down"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/iv_down"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This will create a UI where the `iv_up` appears on top of the `iv_down`. Using the `ConstraintLayout` you can position views relative to one another with ease - it is the "better version" of the `RelativeLayout`. So here we set the `iv_down` to be in the top left corner of the view, and `iv_up` to be 50dp from the top and start of the `iv_down` view. Since the views are ordered as such in the XML, the `iv_up` will always sit on top of the `iv_down` due to its Z positioning.  You can change this by setting specific values for the `android:translationZ` attribute.

Simply setting the `android:alpha="0.5"` attribute on the `iv_up` view, will cause the view to be 50% transparent. You can play with this float value from 0-1 to get the desired look for the transparency.  Changing the margins on `iv_up` will also change how far the view moves from the top left corner i.e. how much of the views overlap!

Comment: It worked, thank you very much!